# Vue.js - Push to object without tracking

Tags: javascript, object, components, vue.js

I've got an object called `Attendees` and another object called `TempAttendee`. A form is bound to `TempAttendee` and when the user submits that form, it takes `TempAttendee` and pushes it to `Attendees`.

The problem is that any further changes to the form will edit that attendee in the `Attendees` object due to the reactivity. How can I get around that?

```
<template> 
    <div>
        <ul class="attendeeEditor">
            <li class="attendeeEditor__attendee" v-for="(attendee, index) in attendees">
                <span class="attendeeEditor__field">{{ attendee.email }}</span>
            </li>
            <li class="attendeeEditor__attendee attendeeEditor__form">            
                <input v-on:keydown.enter="addAttendee" class="attendeeEditor__field" placeholder="Email Address..." type="email" v-model="tempAttendee.email" required />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'attendee-picker',
        data: function() {
            return {
                attendees: {},
                tempAttendee: {
                    email: ""
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addAttendee: function(event) {
                this.attendees.push(this.tempAttendee);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push copy and maybe clear temp.

```
methods: {
            addAttendee: function(event) {
                this.attendees.push(Object.assign({}, this.tempAttendee));
                this.tempAttendee = { email: '' }
            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply your suggestion to my code, I've updated my question to include it. I don't want to create a copy of an attendee into the `tempAttendee` object, but the other way round, add the `tempAttendee` to the `Attendees` object.

Comment: Ok. It was not clear before your code. Then just push copy of temp to Attendees

Comment: Ahh so close, just the `Object.assign` I was missing, thanks for your help!